# Create Join Between Tables Laravel

Tags: laravel, join

I Have 2 tables : Posts - Comment

I Want to Make Relation Between These 2 Tables and Need to Update The Comment That Has "1" Post_ID :

Route:

> Route::get('join', 'JoinController@Join');

Controller :

```
public function Join()
{
    $Comment = Posts::find(1)->Comment;
    $Comment->Title = "JOIN";
    $Comment->save();
}
```

Posts Model :

```
public function Comment()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Comment');
}
```

Comment Model :

```
public function Posts()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Posts');
}
```

but i recieve this error :

> Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: `$Comment = Posts::find(1)->Comment()->first();`

Comment: bro, this is not worked

Comment: do you have any comment with that post id?? try dd($comment) and show us

Answer (score 0):

Do this instead:

```
$comment = new Comment;
$comment->Title = 'JOIN';
#comment->post_id = 1;
$comment->save();
```

Or you can use `create()` method:

```
$Comment = Posts::find(1)->Comment()->create(['Title' => 'JOIN']);
```

If you'll use `create()` method, make sure `Title` is in the `$fillable` array.

Comment: dude, Call to a member function Comment() on a non-object

Comment: @Mohammad This means you don't have post with ID = 1 in DB

Answer (score 0):

```
$Comment = Posts::find(1)->Comment()->first();
$Comment->Title = "JOIN";
$Comment->save();
```

Comment: he says update, so there will be some comment i guess